# Java reading file with specifying memory limit

Tags: java, io, iterator, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

Hi I'm just wondering if it's possible to limit the memory size of (JVM) while reading a text file which is more than 2gb size using LineIterator form Apache or BufferedReader or Scanner?
Let's say I have 2gb text file and I want to read 500mb only for that file. And when I reach the 500mb, I will destroy the variable(String) that holding the data and it will continue again to read the text file with another 500mb until it reach the max size of the text file. So it's like splitting the text file by 500mb.

```
    LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file,"UTF-8");

    String line = null;

            try {
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                    line = it.nextLine();


                    }
```

Comment: Easiest way - create a `500mb` `byte[]` and fill it.

Comment: But the data is String not bytes

Comment: Everything in a file is bytes. You could create a `char[]` if you want.

Comment: Should I store the data lines in byte[]? And i'll create statement If byte[] reach 500mb.

Comment: What do you mean _And i'll create statement If byte[] reach 500mb_. An array has a specific size.

Comment: Yep but, if I just have 2gb installed RAM and the file is more than 2gb. It means i'll get error java heap space.

Comment: How? Why? An array has **a specific size**.

Comment: The file is CSV. And I just want to get a specific indexes. That's why I need to store it to something.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file using BufferedReader(Reader in,int sz)

BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\data\input-file.txt"),8 * 1024)

Comment: What is the meaning of 8*1024? IS it declaring for the max size?

Comment: thats the size I have tried, please go ahead and change